# Ext.container.Container layout

Tags: extjs

How to nest border layout panel inside the `Ext.container.Container` and `container.Container` is rendered to a `div` ?

The main reason for this type of rendering is that, to show a logo at the top of the page.

NOTE: viewport renders in whole browser. so, it cannot be used to display the logo at the top of the page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse border layout with Viewport container. Viewport can't be rendered to a div but an ordinary container can be, and you can use border layout with any kind of container, including Panels. Just try it out.